# How to Determine if One or More Fields in Custom Edit Form have Validation Errors

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, jquery, custom-form, validation

So I have a DVWP with an Edit Form. The form uses jQuery tabs to organize the fields for the different roles that edit the item. I would like to show a message at the top of the form if at least one fields fail validation. Is there a simple way to do this that keeps all OTB column validation fully functional?

Comment: Why not use the validation for the field? http://adicodes.com/column-validations-and-list-validations-in-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed a simple method to determine if there was at least on error in a form field on any of the tabs. Because ms-error is present in the DOM before an error has occurred (people picker), I had to find a different way. Also, because different fields render the error message in different ways, I had to account for all methods in my form. What I ended up doing was targeting the three methods that I found.

```
var varTaskTitleHasError = $("span span[role='alert']").length;
var varTaskDateHasError = $("span #DateTimeFieldErrorMessage").length;
//I only had one People Picker field so the method below might not work when more than one is present.
var varTaskAssignHasError = $("span .ms-error").text();
```

Then I tested on these variables

```
if(varTaskTitleHasError > 0 || varTaskDateHasError > 0 || varTaskAssignHasError !== ""){
    ...Do Something
}
else{
    ...Do Nothing
}
```

So if an error message was found, I did a .show() on my error message that rendered above the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to search for the error message span with class .ms-error and append the column title to your message element in the top of the form.

Could be something like:

```
$(".ms-error").each(function(){
    $("#myValidationMessage").append($(this).closest("td.ms-formbody nobr").text());
});
```

You can add this to $(document).ready(), because the page reloads on validation errors.